# Parsing a csv file with column data in Python

Tags: python, csv

I want to read the first 3 columns of a csv file and do some modification before storing them.
Data in csv file:

`{::[name]str1_str2_str3[0]},1,U0.00 - Sensor1 Not Ready\nTry Again,1,0,12`

`{::[name]str1_str2_str3[1]},2,U0.00 - Sensor2 Not Ready\nTry Again,1,0,12`

From the column1, I just want to parse the value 0 or 1 within the [ ].
Then the value in column2
From column3, I want to parse the substring "Sensor1 Not Ready". Then convert to upper case and replace the space with underscore (eg - SENSOR1_NOT_READY). And then print the string in a new column.

Parsing format -

`**<value from column 1>.<value from column 2>.<string from column 3>**`

I am new to coding in Python. Can someone help me with this? What is the best and the most efficient way to do this?
TIA

What I have tried so far -

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list)

with open('filename.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            columns[i].append(row[i])
    columns = dict(columns)
```

Is this a good way for Column 3?

```
x = # Parsed data from Column 3'
a, b = x.split("\n") # 'a' denotes the substring before \n
c, d = a.split("-") # 'd' denotes the substring after '-'
e = d.upper()
new_str = str.replace(" ", "_")
print new_str
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the python docs for the `csv` module?

Comment: Yes I did go through that. The only thing I managed to understand was how to read the csv file.

Comment: If you can show us the code you've tried for the bit you're struggling with, we can try to help you. If you don't show any code, you probably wont get much help.

Comment: @TomDalton I have added a code snippet to my original post.

Comment: Ok, so I can see you've got `columns` as a defaultdict, with the keys being the CSV line numbers. Each value is a list representing the cells in that CSV row. But, you said your problem is around parsing data from the columns? What have you tried for that bit? It might be worth asking a new question, and leaving out the info about CSVs (as that doesn't seem to be an issue) and instead focussing on 'How do I parse X out of Y?', along with a small snippet of what you're tried for that.

Comment: hints : look at the `str` methods - notably `str.upper()`, `str.split(<delimiter>)` and `str.replace(<target>, <replacement>)` - and the `re` module (regular expressions).

Comment: @TomDalton That is what I need help with! I have 2 questions - How to parse data from the columns? And how to parse X out of Y(especially in the column1)?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thank you for the suggestions. I am looking into this.

Comment: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/06/08/python-an-intro-to-regular-expressions/ is a nice intro to regular expressions.

Comment: I did some editing for parsing a substring for Column 3, is this the best way? I edited my initial post. Kindly check

Comment: Hmm, I can see an embedded `\n`. Is it an actual newline or is it the 2 characters \ and `n`?

Comment: Its an actual newline

Comment: That's sad. The csv module can process embedded newlines **provided the field is enclosed in quotes**. If it is not the case, you will have to do a manual processing. But IMHO, it just means that the input file is not a true CSV file and that a custom parser is probably a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to read a whole line as a string, and then extract desired data with `re` module like this:

```
import re

term = '\[(\d)\].*,(\d+),.*-\s([\w\s]+)\\n'

line = '{::[name]str1_str2_str3[0]},1,U0.00 - Sensor1 Not Ready\nTry Again,1,0,12'
capture = list(re.search(term, line).groups())
capture[-1] = '_'.join(capture[-1].split()).upper()
result = ','.join(capture)
#0,1,Sensor1_Not_Ready
```

Comment: @SergeBallesta Why do I need to do that?

Comment: That could be done with if `line.startswith('{'): ...` to skip complex logic.

Comment: You don't if `\n` is inside line string.