# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups' - re.search

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to parse first 3 elements of a row in a CSV file. The following is the data in the CSV file:

```
{::[name]str1_str2_str3[0]},1,U0.00 - Sensor1 Not Ready\nTry Again,1,0,12
```

I want to parse the value 0 or 1 within the [ ] from the first element. Then the value in second element. From third element, I want to parse the substring "Sensor1 Not Ready", then convert it to UPPERCASE and replace the space with underscore (eg - SENSOR1_NOT_READY). And then print the string in a new column.

As suggested in one of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934884/parsing-a-csv-file-with-column-data-in-python),

I did the following -

```
import csv
import re

with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        tag_name = row[0] # Column A
        bit_num = row[1] # Column B
        error_name = row[2] # Column C

        term0 = '\[(\d)\].*'
        term1 = '(\d+)'
        term2 = '.*-\s([\w\s]+)\\n'

        capture0 = list(re.search(term0, tag_name).groups())
        capture1 = list(re.search(term1, bit_num).groups())
        capture2 = list(re.search(term2, error_name).groups())
```

When I tried to print capture2, I got the following error -

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Can somebody explain what it means and what modifications I need to make?

Comment: what's in your data file? I can make it work all right. It cannot be like this in your datafile because \n should be quoted, else csv module complains: I get `U0.00 - Sensor1 Not Ready` for capture 2.

Comment: I just want to print out `Sensor1 Not Ready` and not the entire thing. I figured out the error, thanks to @Zachary

Comment: check my answer, your file must contain a _literal_ `\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs when the `re` module does not find a match and you want to ask for the `.groups()` function.
You could either use a `try/except` mechanism:

```
try:
    capture2 = list(re.search(term2, error_name).groups())
except NoneType:
    capture2 = None
```

... or a simple `if/else` block:

```
m = re.search(term2, error_name)
if m:
    capture2 = list(m.groups())
else:
    capture2 = None
```

The underlying problem here is that your expression does not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

If `re.search` finds no matches for your regular expression, it will return `None`.  You should check that the return value from `re.search()` returns a result before attempting to call `.groups()`:

```
result = re.search(term2, error_name)
capture2 = list(result.groups()) if result else None
```

Answer (score 0):

the third expression doesn't match because the data in the file is

```
{::[name]str1_str2_str3[0]},1,U0.00 - Sensor1 Not Ready\nTry Again,1,0,12
```

but `\n` is there *literally* (it's *not* a newline, it's backslash, followed by `\n`). It can't be otherwise since newlines need quoting else `csv` module complains and your data doesn't have quotes.

In regular expressions `\\n`, unescaped, still means newline. You should match like this:

```
term2 = r'.*-\s([\w\s]+)\\n'
```

Thanks to raw prefix now regex looks for literal `\n`

Comment: Thank you Jean. I understood the mistake. And it works perfectly now!